# Any way to send HDMI-CEC commands in tvOS?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, hdmi

I'm curious if it's possible for an app running on an Apple TV 4 / tvOS 9 to send HDMI-CEC commands to the TV. Specifically, I'm interested in if it's possible to change the TV's input to something other than the Apple TV.

I suspect that this isn't possible with public APIs in tvOS 9, but I'm curious if there are. And I'm open to private APIs as well. (This isn't for an app that I'm planning to submit to the app store!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible in tvOS 9.0